# Определение наличия приложения на другом устройстве

Tags: android, whatsapp, viber

1. В **Whatsapp** при создании нового чата выбирается адресат из адресной книги телефона, при чем выводится список только тех, у кого **Whatsapp** установлен. Как это реализовано? Как мое приложение может получить информацию, что оно установлено на устройстве другого пользователя, но который есть в моей телефонной книге?
2. Как, с помощью каких средств реализовано уведомление о том, что тот или иной контакт из Вашей телефонной книги установил себе **Viber**?

Спасибо.

Comment: Все это реализуется, очевидно, через сервер.

Comment: Согласен, очевидно, но хочется как-то по-жирнее инфу получить...

Comment: 1. Да очень просто реализовано. Приложение WhatsApp посылает всю вашу телефонную книгу целиком на сервер. Там идет сравнение ваших телефонов с глобальной базой. Если есть совпадение - ваше приложение получает инфу от сервера, что этот тел номер подключен к WhatsApp. Вот и все. 2. Когда новый чел устанавливает себе Viber, то его номер заносится в глобальную базу на сервере и запускается проверка - какие еще номера знают этот номер. Всем, кто знает, отсылается уведомление.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, кажется ваш коммент можно как ответ вполне оформить)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну ок, оформлю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Да очень просто реализовано. Приложение WhatsApp посылает всю вашу телефонную книгу целиком на сервер. Там идет сравнение ваших телефонов с глобальной базой. Если есть совпадение - ваше приложение получает инфу от сервера, что этот тел номер подключен к WhatsApp. Вот и все.
2. Когда новый чел устанавливает себе Viber, то его номер заносится в глобальную базу на сервере и запускается проверка - какие еще номера знают этот номер. Всем, кто знает, отсылается уведомление.